# Number of Pictures

Tags: python

This code is if I submit a certain number, it would produce the biggest perimeter. But the question is I don't get the last two lines (excluding 'print' line) and how it works.. Why does x has to be 1 in order to make this code work? how does it know what 'minVal' is in perimeter < minVal line?

```
    number = int(input("Please enter a number: "))


    for x in range (1, number+1):
       if number % x == 0:
           y = number / x
           perimeter = 2*x +2*y

           if x == 1 or perimeter < minVal:
              minVal = perimeter

    print (minVal)
```

Comment: The operator `or` in Python uses short-circuit evaluation: if its left operand is `True`, it does not evaluate its right operand. At the first iteration of your loop, `x` has the value of `1`, so the condition `x==1` is true and the missing value of `minVal` is not involved in the evaluation. Since the condition is true, the body of the `if` statement is executed, and `minVal` is initialized.